# Conditionally deleting rows in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

How I can delete rows in Power BI based on conditions? In some columns I have both numerical and text data. I need only this numerical type.

Answer (score 0):

```
= Table.SelectRows(t, each [col] is number)
```